# Loading 15GB file in Python

Tags: python, file, dictionary, loading

I have a 15GB text file containing 25000 lines. 
I am creating a multi level dictionary in Python of the form : 
    dict1 = {'':int}, 
    dict2 = {'':dict1}.

I have to use this entire dict2 multiple times (about 1000...in a for loop) in my program. 
Can anyone please tell a good way to do that.

The same type of information is stored in the file
(count of different RGB values of 25000 images. 1 image per line)
eg : 1 line of the file would be like :
image1 : 255,255,255-70 ; 234,221,231-40 ; 112,13,19-28 ;
image2 : 5,25,25-30 ; 34,15,61-20 ; 102,103,109-228 ;
and so on.

Comment: It certainly would eat at least 15GB of RAM in practice (and perhpas 2 or 4 times as much). Do you have at least 16GBytes?

Comment: It would help to know more about how this data is used. Do you really need arbitrary random access to the entire data structure at every point in the application? Maybe you only need one image's data at a time, or one colour's data at a time?

Comment: Have either of the answers below helped?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to use chunking.

```
def read_in_chunks(file_object, chunk_size=1024):
    """Lazy function (generator) to read a file piece by piece.
    Default chunk size: 1k."""
    while True:
        data = file_object.read(chunk_size)
        if not data:
            break
        yield data

f = open('really_big_file.dat')
for piece in read_in_chunks(f):
    process_data(piece)
```

As a note as you start to process large files moving to a map-reduce idiom may help as you'll be able to work on separate chunked files independently without pulling the complete data set into memory.

Answer (score 1):

In python, if you use a file object as an iterator, you can read a file line by line without opening the whole thing in memory.

```
for line in open("huge_file.txt"):
    do_something_with(line)
```

Comment: Sorry, for the incomplete comment.
I am doing  this.

handle = open("large_file")
for line in handle:
   (key,a) = line.split(':')
   tempdic = a.split(';')
   for line2 in tempdic:
      (k,v) = line2.split('-')
      dict1[k] = v
   dict2[key] = dict1

Please see the original question for data format in the file.

Thanks again

Comment: @user2013985 you can use `file.seek(0)` method to go to the beginning of the file.